# How to replace subarrays with the sum of their elements?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-sum

```
Array
(
    [Apr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 392
            [2] => 140
            [3] => 250
        )

    [May] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 392
            [2] => 140
            [3] => 250
        )
)
```

I want to have a result array that will be holding sum  like this

```
Array
(
    [Apr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 849
        )

    [May] => Array
        (
            [0] => 849
        )
)
```

Comment: read [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rakesh Tripathi simply try with foreach() and array_sum() like below:

```
<?php
$array =     array(
                "Apr" => array(
                        67,
                        392,
                        140,
                        250
                    ),
                "May" => array(
                        67,
                        392,
                        140,
                        250
                    )
            );
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = array_sum($value);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean looking functional syntax using `array_map()` and `array_sum()`:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83927a153251d1ee1663503d54206ee7358a63c0))

```
$array=[
    "Apr"=>[67,392,140,250],
    "May"=>[67,392,140,250]
];

var_export(array_map('array_sum',$array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Apr' => 849,
  'May' => 849,
)
```